# Access iCloud Drive on behalf of user from a server

Tags: ios, cloudkit, icloud-drive

In my iOS app I would like to:

- get an access token to add files to iCloud Drive on behalf of the user
- send this access token to the server
- the server will then upload files to the user's iCloud Drive.

This is possible with Dropbox and Google Drive.

Is this possible with iCloud Drive? I have looked at [Cloudkit Webservices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) but it seems to talk only about databases and records, never about files.

Maybe I am missing something?